# Set an expiration date (and time) for a pop up that has a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

What can I add to the following that will prevent the pop up from loading after 8pm on New Years Eve?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Start Cookie for PopUp
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('colorframe=true') === -1) {
    var expires = new Date();
    expires.setDate(expires.getDate()+1);
    document.cookie = "colorframe=true; escKey=true; expires="+expires.toUTCString();

        // Start Popup
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.colorbox({
                escKey: true,
                html: '<a href="---"><img src="---" width="550" height="550" alt="New Years Eve at ---"/></a>'
            });
        }, 2000);
    };
});
```

Comment: 8pm according to their local time zone or your server's time zone?

Comment: Great question. GMT-5 or EST...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare the current timestamp with the timestamp for 8pm. Using http://www.epochconverter.com/ I believe this is 1483232400000.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Start Cookie for PopUp
    if ((new Date).getTime() > 1483232400000) return;

    //remainder of code here

});
```

This is assuming you trust your clients' computers time.

Comment: What it be better if tonight at 8 I add a code that says 'after 48 hours do not show the following popup' --- how would i do that? @yts

Comment: @mdnash I don't think that would be better. I do think it would be ideal if you can do the time check on the server when you render the html (set some kind of global javascript variable) so that you're not depending on clients' time

Comment: @mdnash if you don't have access to the server code, then just use the javascript solution I posted